# Got this error when trying to install avast

Tags: software-installation

help a newbie!
Tryed to download Avast and this message shows up?
Some one who care to explain slowly and in a kind way, what the message means, and if I can fix it myself?

```
Archive:  /home/lars/Hentede filer/avast_internet_security_setup_online.exe
[/home/lars/Hentede filer/avast_internet_security_setup_online.exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/lars/Hentede filer/avast_internet_security_setup_online.exe or
          /home/lars/Hentede filer/avast_internet_security_setup_online.exe.zip, and cannot find /home/lars/Hentede filer/avast_internet_security_setup_online.exe.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: Note that avast is no longer developed for Linux and problems with it wont have any support...

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to download a Windows executable (`.exe`), those don't work on Linux unless you use a wrapper like [`wine`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine). More importantly, you don't need an antivirus on Linux. While [there are actually a few viruses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware#Viruses) around, they are either harmless, or very old and in any case you can safely ignore them.

I have been using Linux at home and professionally for more than 15 years and have never, ever, needed to install an antivirus. If you really want to, just install one that has a [Linux version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware#Anti-virus_applications).